# Is it possible to search over multiple Google Forums from one search box?

Tags: search, google-groups, embed, forums

I've embedded several Google forums in our website, found at: http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/forums.html, following the general guidelines found at:
http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1191206

While you do see searches over individual forums when you click on the name of that forum, I'd like there to be a way to search over multiple related forums from one search box.

Is this possible? Would a Google Custom Search Engine work for this purpose? (Off to try that now)